# Math riddle solution way??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For all real numbers $b$ and $c$ such that the product of $c$ and $3$ is $b$, which of the following expressions represents the sum of $c$ and $3$ in terms of $b$?

$$\text{A) }b+3,\quad \text{B) }3b+3,\quad \text{C) }3(b+3),\quad \text{D) }\frac{b+3}{3},\quad \text{E) } \frac{b}{3}+3.$$

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stack exchange.  This question should be tagged algebra-precalculus, not calculus

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, what is your doubt? Your answer is correct.

Comment: Which answer is correct i haven't given one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with $$3c=b,$$ then $$c=\frac{b}{3},$$ then $$c+3=\frac{b}{3}+3,$$ and finally $$\frac{b}{3}+3.$$